# How can I use custom forms fields like table for symfony form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In Symfony docs they say to use this

```
<div>
    {{ form_label(form.task) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.task) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.task) }}
</div>
```

But this generates the label element.

But I want to have table `<td>` instead of `<label>`

And also for the input `textbox`, I want to mention the size of text box. Where can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define your [form theme](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).

Probably, [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-theming) is what you are looking for